# Are darknet network related questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

For example:

- Can you open I2P pages without having I2P installed?
- How Hornet high-speed onion routing compares to other overlay networks such as Tor or I2P?
- Where are the files stored in GNUnet network?
- Why doesn't Google index the darknet?
- How can you access the darknet from a Chromebook?
- How to access IRC, BitTorrent or other services via I2P?
- How to connect to FTP via I2P?
- How do I register new I2P hostname?
- How does I2P prevent domain names from being spoofed?
- How to configure web browser to open I2P websites?
- etc.

Above are just few samples, but I'm asking about in general about the darknet.

Comment: I think these questions are more suited to the DeepWeb beta site http://deepweb.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DavidPostill The site is [closing down](http://meta.deepweb.stackexchange.com/q/124/128), so I'm checking whether they can be suitable here, so we can request the migration of some of them.

Comment: Aah. That's a shame. :/

Comment: Most of those questions are not suitable Q&A questions honestly.  Most of the "how to", "why does google not", "comparison" questions are very difficult questions to write so they are helpful to the community (IMO)

Comment: These are just sample questions without the body context, as I wanted just check the darknet in general (not specifically these questions). Full list can be found [here](http://meta.deepweb.stackexchange.com/a/129/128) (you can access the site via [Visit!](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/87978/deep-web) link). So you may remove from the list which one are not suitable (after reading the full context).

Comment: Compare the body to the help center, if a question isn't well researched, it's unlikely to be found helpful.  A beta site can, or even needs good questions that, are written to self-answer or use as canonical question (I.e how do I remove malware) as example.

Answer (score 3):

1. Can you open I2P pages without having I2P installed? yes
2. How Hornet high-speed onion routing compares to other overlay networks such as Tor or I2P? opinion based I think
3. Where are the files stored in GNUnet network? not sure.
4. Why doesn't Google index the darknet? You'd need to be google to answer that
5. How can you access the darknet from a Chromebook? "the darknet" is too broad I think
6. How to access IRC, BitTorrent or other services via I2P? maybe as seperate questions like
7. How to connect to FTP via I2P? Yes